# JSON Tree structure with the key Folder on each level

Tags: python, json, tree

I will make requests to an API that have a folder structure.

Some request may respons with one level, others with 20 levels but I don't want this ugly structure.

Is there any good explanation for doing this recursive without knowing level depth?

```
for parent_folder in server_folders['folders']:
    print(parent_folder['name'] + ' (PARENT)')

    for children in parent_folder['folders']:
        print("- " + children['name'])

        for sub_children in children['folders']:
            print("- - " + sub_children['name'])

            for sub_sub_children in sub_children['folders']:
                print("- - - " + sub_sub_children['name'])

                for sub_sub_sub_children in sub_sub_children['folders']:
                    print("- - - " + sub_sub_sub_children['name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd solve this with recursion.

So by creating a method, called `nested_list_print`, with two parameters,
the nested list that you are looping through, and how deep you want the depth to be.

like so:

```py
def nested_list_print(init_folder, init_depth, depth=0):
    for i in init_folder:
        print('-'*depth + i)
        if depth > 0:
            nested_list(i, init_depth-1, depth+1)
```

Now you can call the method with a depth of ex. 3 like this: `nested_list_print(input_list, 3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Asger, smart!

I did end up with this rewrite of you excellent job!

```
def nested_list_print(init_folder, init_depth):
for i in init_folder['folders']:
    print('- '*(init_depth) + i['name'])
    if 'folders' in i:
        nested_list_print(i, init_depth+1)


nested_list_print(jsonfeed_w_folders, 0)
```